# Why does the coefficient name not appear in the output when running the Cox Proportional Hazards model of the Survival package?

Tags: r, cox-regression, survival

I'm running the `coxph()` function from the `survival` package, and am using an example from http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/cox-proportional-hazards-model, using univariate Cox regression and the lung cancer data provided in the “lung” dataset of the survival package. When I run the code posted at the bottom, I get the output shown in the image immediately below for the `res.cox` object. It supposedly, per the link, compares the hazard (risk of death) of the female subset of the sex variable against the baseline subset of males. However, this output doesn't show which subset is being compared against which baseline of the variable under study. Is there way to run the `coxph()` function so the comparison bases are shown? I've read through the survival package documentation and couldn't find how to generate this. It should at a minimum indicate "female" for the regression coefficient, and it would be nice if it also showed the baseline that female is being compared against. In this case, there are only 2 subsets of the sex variable, but there are other variables with more than two subsets and it would be helpful to see the comparisons labeled.

[image]

Code:

```
library(survival)
library(survminer)

### Example data set ###
head(lung)

### Univariate Cox regression ###
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
res.cox
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In such cases we sociologists usually create a `female` dummy.

```
library(survival)

lung$female <- +(lung$sex == 2)

coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ female, data = lung)
# Call:
# coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ female, data = lung)
# 
#           coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z       p
# female -0.5310    0.5880   0.1672 -3.176 0.00149
# 
# Likelihood ratio test=10.63  on 1 df, p=0.001111
# n= 228, number of events= 165
```

Comment: hi @jay.sf what is the role of the + in front of the the condition ?

Comment: @Wael It coerces to integer (think a `0` in front of the `+`), you could also say `as.integer(lung$sex == 2)` but the former is shorter.

Comment: Nice trick it could be helpful and less cumbersome than as.integer.

Answer (score 1):

In lung data the sex variable is coded as numeric one.
You could transform it to categorical variable using `factor` or a character variable

```
class(lung$sex)
[1] "numeric"

lung=lung%>%
mutate(sex=ifelse(sex==1,"male","female"))
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
res.cox

Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

          coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z       p
sexmale 0.5310    1.7007   0.1672 3.176 0.00149

Likelihood ratio test=10.63  on 1 df, p=0.001111
n= 228, number of events= 165
```

In the output male is compared against female which is taken as ref.
You can change this by transforming it to factor and changing the ref

```
lung$sex=relevel(factor(lung$sex),ref="male")
res.cox <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)
res.cox
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ sex, data = lung)

             coef exp(coef) se(coef)      z       p
sexfemale -0.5310    0.5880   0.1672 -3.176 0.00149

Likelihood ratio test=10.63  on 1 df, p=0.001111
n= 228, number of events= 165
```